# why version of installed jupyter lab is different from listed version?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

From below website, it say latest version in anaconda is 3.4.8.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyterlab

so I am trying to update jupyter lab version from existing 3.3.3 to 3.4.8 using

conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab

after installation, I used conda list to check jupyter lab version and it is still 3.3.2

how do I update the version?

Thanks

Comment: Visit this link: https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/use/upgrade-notebook.html

Comment: I did and using conda list still find old version of jupyter lab which is different from the website

Comment: now I tried to install version manually by doing conda install jupyterlab=3.4.8, it says  PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - jupyterlab=3.4.8